# How to recreate Akka Stream source in case of error

Tags: akka, akka-stream

Is it possible to create a recreatable akka stream source and how to achive that behaviour? For example I would like the following helper method:

```
def recreatable[T, Mat](source: => Source[T, Mat], delay: Duration)(implicit mat: ActorMaterializer): Source[T, Mat] = ...
// using helper method
recreatable(new MySource(...), 1 minute).map(...)
```

Any help will be really apprecited. Thx in advance

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would require dynamic reattaching of sources in a materialized graph. This can't be done easily, and AFAIK akka-streams does not provide an explicit way to do it, except `flatMap` combinators.

Comment: Really bad :( I'm developing JMS connectors implementing reactive interfaces, so I would like to restart/recreate just a pubsher instead of recreating entire a stream.

Comment: Then it is probably better to model the restarting publisher as a single source. That is, you need to move the reconnection logic to the materialized state of the source instead of making the materialization establish a connection to the bus once. You can do it using an actor, for example, which always tries to keep the connection and which fails when you want the entire system to fail (e.g. after a sufficient number of failed attempts).

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev, thank you very much for the explanation. I'll try to do some research again.